# android, put two activities on stack simultaneously

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-task

My app main launcher is the `LoginActivity` which, in most of the cases, at the end start `MainActivity` from where all actions in my app can be launched

This is the "normal" scenario

however, when someone lauches the app from share context, or notification the `LoginActivity` redirects him straight to the activity responsible for handling that specific scenario...

this way when the user presses "back" on cellphone the activity stack goes back to login, instead of main

How can i tell login activity to put two activities on stack in order to create this "fake" back history

Comment: use onbackpressed() and handle by intent ,or use launch mode for loginactivity

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder .  It will help you create the back stack you are looking for.

Comment: my app is api lvl 15